# What listener() does in the Redux store?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm watching Dan Abramov's Redux videos on Egghead. In the video where he implements the Redux Store from scratch, he includes this code (around 1:28 - https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-implementing-store-from-scratch):

```
const dispatch = (action) => {
  state = reducer(state, action);
  listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
};
```

So this code iterates through each item in the listener array, and I understand that each listener needs to be updated, but I don't get what listener() is doing. Where does this function come from?

Answer (score 3):

`createStore` method have `listeners` variable. It is an array of functions which should be called when store updates.
You can add your own function into `listeners` through the `subscribe` method of `store`.

For example:

```
const store = createStore(reducer);
store.subscribe(state => console.log(state)); // add function into listeners
store.dispatch(action);
```

Function with `console.log` will be called after state will changed.

Comment: while this could work in 2016 (don't know, didn't check it) in v4 (2018) this works:

store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#subscribe-listener

Comment: Okay, I understand. It runs whatever function (e.g. a function that changes the number in navbar-icon-shopping-cart). This example function would have initially been passed into the store.subscribe(listener); as listener.                                         The line just make sure UI state update functions are called straight after state is changed.

Comment: So all the listener functions in the listener array are looped through every time actions are dispatched. Isn't this inefficiency?

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is called an **arrow function** and is new to ECMAScript 6.  Without the special syntax, that code would look like this:

```
listeners.forEach(function(listener){
    return listener();
});
```

listener**s** is an array of functions.  listeners is being iterated over with the Array.prototype.forEach function which takes a function as it's parameter.

'listener' in that context is the variable name given to the function passed into the lambda expression.

When the Array.prototype.forEach function invokes your function, it passes in the current item in the iteration.  in this code that item is a function and it's just being invoked.

To put it simply, this code will iterate over an array of functions and invoke each one.

It might help to understand the API for the Array.prototype.forEach function.  Here's the documentation:

**Array.prototype.forEach**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

**Arrow Functions**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Listen is a method on the store that takes a handler. The handler is a function that when called causes the DOM to render:

```js
store.listen(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>{JSON.stringify(store.getState(), null, 2)}</div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
});
```

The way I understand it is that the listeners array consists of the render function on different React components that are connected to the Redux store.